# Openvpn's client-connect script is not called

Tags: openvpn

I want OpenVPN to run a script when a client connects, but it seems to ignore my client-connect directive.

I am running OpenVPN 2.4.0 on Raspbian. In my server.conf, I have

```
...
script-security 3
# this is the "up" directive but the issue is the same as with client-connect
up /etc/openvpn/up.sh
...
```

/etc/openvpn/up.sh is owned by root by world-executable (`rwxr-xr-x`), and it is as simple as

```
#!/bin/sh
whoami >> /tmp/connect.txt
exit 0
```

I can successfully connect to my server, `/var/log/daemon.log` even states 
`ovpn-server[2050]: /etc/openvpn/up.sh tun0 1500 1621 10.100.0.1 10.100.0.2 init` without stating any error, yet nothing appears on /tmp, as if my script was not called.

What is going wrong?

Comment: FWIW, here is my full server.conf
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca   /etc/openvpn/certs/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/certs/keys/....crt
key  /etc/openvpn/certs/keys/...key
dh /etc/openvpn/certs/....pem
server 10.100.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS ..."
push "dhcp-option DNS ..."

script-security 3
up /etc/openvpn/up.sh

keepalive 10 120
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/certs/keys/ta.key 0
cipher AES-256-CBC
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 9
explicit-exit-notify 1
auth ...
tls-cipher ...

Comment: Sorry for the missing newlines :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm eventually replying to myself.

OpenVPN was launched as a systemd service (target?), and its config file stated `PrivateTmp=true`. So it *did* work and the script was actually run, but it did not write in the actual /tmp folder.

And by the way, one should also use the full path to the binaries (e.g. `/usr/bin/whoami`), since the `$PATH` of the executed script may not be the same as the one of regular shells.

Comment: And, for a production system, `script-security 2` is enough. And the script does not need to be world-executable, just executable by openvpn's user.